# Parsing all prices of same field name if found in sheet from json data vba in a listbox and let user choose

Tags: excel, vba, api

So I have some json formatted data, in which an article name (the field in my case is "description courte") can be used multiple times and have a different price each time, I want to get those prices and display them in a `listbox` and let the user pick which one to parse in the column "price" which is `found.offset(0,3)`. Note that I only search for fields that exist in the `Range("G:G")` This is what I did so far :

This code is returning an error : `index does not belong in the selection` (sorry if translated badly) at the

> Set Found = Range("G:G").Find(ArtDict.Items()(Index).Name)

**Code example**

```
Sub prix()
Dim http As New WinHttpRequest
Dim resp As String
Dim url As String

url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/appY6Wo3AmLHqHkjr/Materiaux?api_key=key_here" & Fields
http.Open "GET", url, False
http.Send
Dim JSON As Object
Dim Found As Range
Dim ArtDict As New Dictionary, Article As class_Article
Dim Index As Long, count As Long
Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.ResponseText)
    For Index = 1 To JSON("records").count
    Set Found = Range("G:G").Find(ArtDict.Items()(Index).Name)
        If Not ArtDict.Exists(JSON("records")(Index)("fields")("description courte")) Then
            'If this article doesn't exist in the article dictionary, then create the article object and add it to the dictionary
            Set Article = New class_Article
            Article.Name = JSON("records")(Index)("fields")("description courte")
            Article.ParsePrice JSON("records")(Index)("fields")("prix unitaire HT")
            Debug.Print Article.Name, Article.HighPrice, Article.LowPrice
            ArtDict.Add Article.Name, Article
        Else
            Set Article = ArtDict(JSON("records")(Index)("fields")("description courte"))
            Article.ParsePrice JSON("records")(Index)("fields")("prix unitaire HT")
            Debug.Print Article.Name, Article.HighPrice, Article.LowPrice
            Set ArtDict(JSON("records")(Index)("fields")("description courte")) = Article
        End If
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        count = Found.Offset(0, 4).Value + 1
        If count > 1 Then
        UserForm1.Show
        UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem (Article.HighPrice)
        UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem (Article.LowPrice)
        Found.Offset(0, 3) = UserForm1.ListBox1.Value
        End If
        End If
    Next Index
End Sub
```

**JSON SAMPLE**

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "rec0MS66BnYY0vK32",
      "fields": {
        "id": 124,
        "article": "osmo 24m2 3062MAT 0.75L",
        "categorie": [
          "recvw95DBiWvk3zaH"
        ],
        "udv": 1,
        "unité": [
          "recYQ9wpLDgNDk5BW"
        ],
        "prix HT de l'udv": 29.09,
        "date d'achat": "2019-08-01",
        "distributeur": "cotet mtp",
        "reference distributeur": "OSMO-ORI-0.75-M",
        "id facture": "FA19036300",
        "created on": "2020-02-07",
        "by": "remyvignaux",
        "description courte": "osmo 3062MAT",
        "prix unitaire HT": 29.09
      },
      "createdTime": "2021-02-28T20:53:00.000Z"
    },....etc
```

**CLASS_ARTICLE**

```
Option Explicit

Public Name As String
Public HighPrice As Currency
Public LowPrice As Currency

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    HighPrice = -922337203685477.5807@ 'Set value to lowest possible value
    LowPrice = 922337203685477.5807@ 'Set value to the highest possible value
End Sub

Public Function ParsePrice(ByVal NewPrice As Currency) As Boolean
    HighPrice = IIf(NewPrice > HighPrice, NewPrice, HighPrice)
    LowPrice = IIf(NewPrice < LowPrice, NewPrice, LowPrice)
End Function
```

Comment: Could you please share a picture of the error message???

Comment: The JSON file has just one array after the `record` item. Check this documentation [JSON](https://json.org/example.html)

Comment: @ElbertVillarreal No the json file isnt just what i shared , i only shared one record , the error : https://ibb.co/0nLJ8dW and the line : https://ibb.co/hDxqvj5

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be `Set Found = Range("G:G").Find(ArtDict.Items(Index).Name)`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 even like that it returns the same error at the same line

Comment: The `ArtDict` in the `Set Found = Range("G:G").Find(ArtDict.Items()(Index).Name)` line must be initialized

Comment: As @VBasic2008 say in a previous comment.

Comment: @ElbertVillarreal but how would i initialize it if the data is from the api not manually by me ? sorry if its a stupid question im new to vba

Comment: Check this https://ibb.co/VtjSPZc

Comment: There is no stupid questions, no worries. What data are you waiting from the API?? Is that the only source you have to get that information?

Comment: `ArtDict` doesn't have a `Name` property, so it should be `Article` or `JSON` something instead.

Comment: @ElbertVillarreal ok so from the api im getting this table "materiaux" that has a lot of records , here's the full file https://alpes.cloud/show/add90fc7d4 , one single record has what i put in the example ubove , i search by "description courte" for "prix unitaire hdv"

Comment: @VBasic2008 is right... you need to declare the ArtDict first, and you will get another error... Where is the data you want to use in the ArtDict dictionary??? Can I see an example?

Comment: Try to use a [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to check your data.

Comment: May be we can communicate via e-mail... I will try to help.

Comment: Delete!!! that comment... that information is sensitive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the JSON into a collection of articles (using a dictionary) and then process each article in turn. The price selection can be an article method. I used an input box just to show the principle but you could use listbox. The results are shown on Sheet1.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub prix()
   
    ' get json into a string
    Dim fso, ts, s
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\json.txt")
    s = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close

    Dim dictArt As New Dictionary, oArt As Class_Article ' holds articles
    Dim name As String, price As Currency
    Dim JSON As Object, rec, fld
    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)
    
    ' parse json
    For Each rec In JSON("records")
        Set fld = rec("fields")
        name = fld("description courte")
        price = fld("prix unitaire HT")
        
        If dictArt.Exists(name) Then
            dictArt(name).AddPrice price
        Else
            Set oArt = New Class_Article
            oArt.name = name
            oArt.AddPrice price
            dictArt.Add name, oArt
        End If
    Next

    ' result to sheet1
    Dim key, i As Long: i = 1
    Sheet1.Cells.Clear
    Sheet1.Range("A1:C1") = Array("Description", "Price Count", "Price")
    For Each key In dictArt
        i = i + 1
        Set oArt = dictArt(key)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = oArt.Name
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 2) = oArt.PriceCount
        ' if more than once give options
        If oArt.PriceCount > 1 Then
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Select
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            oArt.SelectPrice
            If oArt.bSelected Then
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = oArt.price
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = xlNone
            End If
        Else
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = oArt.price
        End If
    Next
End Sub

' Class_Article

Public name As String
Public price As Currency
Public PriceCount As Integer
Public bSelected As Boolean
Private prices As New Collection
Private i As Integer

Public Sub AddPrice(ByVal price As Currency)
    PriceCount = PriceCount + 1
    Me.price = price
    prices.Add price, CStr(PriceCount)
End Sub

Sub SelectPrice()

   Dim msg As String
   bSelected = False

   ' build option list
   msg = name & " has " & PriceCount & " prices"
   For i = 1 To PriceCount
       msg = msg & vbCr & "(" & i & ") " & prices(i)
   Next

   ' user selects
begin:
   i = Application.InputBox(msg, "Select Price 1 to " & PriceCount, 1, Type:=1) ' int
   
   If i < 1 Then
       Exit Sub
   ElseIf i > PriceCount Then
      GoTo begin
   End If

   ' selected price
   price = prices(i)
   bSelected = True

End Sub
```